# How to extract the actual values from the shap summary plot

Tags: python-3.x, shap

How to go about extracting the numerical values for the `shap` summary plot so that the data can be viewed in a `dataframe`?:

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from shap import Explainer, waterfall_plot, Explanation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Generate noisy Data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, 
                          n_features=50, 
                          n_informative=9, 
                          n_redundant=0, 
                          n_repeated=0, 
                          n_classes=10, 
                          n_clusters_per_class=1,
                          class_sep=9,
                          flip_y=0.2,
                          random_state=17)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = Explainer(model)
sv = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, plot_type="bar")
```

I tried

```
np.abs(shap_values.values).mean(axis=0)
```

but I get a shape of (50,10).  How do I get just the aggerated value for each feature to then sort for the feature importance?

Comment: You're having 50 features with 10 classes so the result is about right

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, in order to get the physical number then, using the image above as a guide, for the first bar, which is feature 3, if we take the 4th row (feature 3) from the generated array from `np.abs(shap_values.values).mean(axis=0)`,  do we add up the numbers in the 10 columns to get the number for feature 3 or find the mean of the 10 columns in row 3?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from shap import Explainer, waterfall_plot, Explanation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from shap import summary_plot


# Generate noisy data
X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=50,
    n_informative=9,
    n_redundant=0,
    n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=10,
    n_clusters_per_class=1,
    class_sep=9,
    flip_y=0.2,
    random_state=17,
)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = Explainer(model)
sv = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

summary_plot(sv, X_train, plot_type="bar")
```

[image]

Note, you have features 3, 29, 34 and so on at the top.

If you do:

```
np.abs(sv).shape
```

---

```
(10, 250, 50)
```

you'll find you've got 10 classes for 250 datapoints for 50 features.

If you aggregate, you'll get everything you need:

```
aggs = np.abs(sv).mean(1)
aggs.shape
```

---

```
(10, 50)
```

You can draw it:

```
sv_df = pd.DataFrame(aggs.T)
sv_df.plot(kind="barh",stacked=True)
```

[image]

And if it still doesn't look familiar, you can rearrange and filter:

```
sv_df.loc[sv_df.sum(1).sort_values(ascending=True).index[-10:]].plot(
    kind="barh", stacked=True
)
```

[image]

Conclusion:

> `sv_df` are aggregated SHAP values, as in summary plot, arranged as features per row and classes per column.

Does it help?

Comment: again, I sincerely THANK YOU for your thorough answer and patience with my questions.  You answer certainly answers my question....THOROUGHLY!  It certainly helps!